# Why is Average Visit Duration different to Average Time on Page, when only one page is viewed?

Tags: google-analytics

I've just checked Google Analytics today and noticed that one of my articles had been viewed just once, and had an Average Time on Page of 00:00:00 hours. I know this hit came from Reddit, because my WordPress stats tell me this - and it's the only hit to have come from Reddit too. However, when I check the Average Visit Duration of the Reddit visit, it says 02:04:48 hours, even though the person who visited the article didn't click any further.

So what's going on here? How come Average Visit Duration ≠ Average Time on Page, in this instance?

(I should add that I have some `_trackEvent` script on my blog which measures the time a user stayed on each page for.)

Answer (score 4):

The time or moment a person leaves a page can not - by conventional methods - be tracked.

Let's say there's a visitor who hits 3 unique pages in a session. Page 1 is loaded at 12:00pm. Page 2 is loaded at 12:05pm. Page 3 is loaded at 12:08pm, and that's the entire visit. The entire session lasted 8 minutes, and the average time per page would be calculated 8 minutes/3 pages = 2.67 minutes per page.

There's a problem here though. How long were they on the last page? We *do* know when they loaded the page. We know that they visited the first page for 5 minutes, because the second one wasn't loaded until 12:05pm. We also know this because this hypothetical visit takes place sequentially; not all visits are perfect like this - e.g. tabbed-browsing.

However, we do *not* know how long they were on this last page because they either timed-out, closed the window, left to go to another site, or what have you. The last page is thrown out from the calculation because we do not know how long they were on that page. **As a result, Google Analytics will report a misleading 00:00:00 time on page. This does not necessarily mean that other script implementations are not causing the problem; without looking at the script installation, it's hard to say.**

Please check out this most excellent explanation of [how time-on-site is calculated](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/standard-metrics-revisited-time-on-page-and-time-on-site/) from my hero, Avinash Kaushik.

Answer (score 0):

Visit duration is affected by pageviews and events.  Time on page is only affected by pageviews, and you need a second pageview in order to calculate the time on page for the first page.

To put it another way...your events are skewing the avg visit duration metric.  Technically that visit is a bounce too.